# Conditional Record Selection in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a lapsed payment report which displays the data in a quarter by Quarter Basis, but evaluated based on the year.

E.g. I would like to return all the Names of people who have payed in previous years, but not this year and display the results by quarter.

I have this so far, however getting it to return the correct names continues to elude me.

```
SELECT 
IDNo, 
Year(now()) as CurrentYear,
concat(year(pdate),'-Q',quarter(pdate)) as YrQtr,
Concat(IDNo,' - ',Fname,' ',Lname) as Fullname,
sum(amt) as Amt

FROM Payments 
GROUP BY fname, lname, YrQtr
Having Sum(if(year(pdate)=Year(now()),1,0)) < 1 and (Sum(if(year(pdate)=Year(now())-1 ,1,0)) >0 or Sum(if(year(pdate)=Year(now())-2 ,1,0)) >0)
```

Any Help, direction, of even letting me know this is impossible would be appreciated.

thanks,

Edit: 
The results would show Payer 1, who has paid in 2012 or 2013 but not 2014, with a Breakdown by Quarter - year

```
2012-Q1   2013-Q3
$xxx       $xxx
```

But not payer 2, who has paid in 2012 and 2014. (or any payer which has paid in 2014)

Comment: Please show example of desired results.

Comment: The results would show payer 1, who has paid in 2012 or 2013 but not 2014, with a Breakdown by Quarter- year 2012-Q1 $xxx, 2013-Q3 $xxx.     But not payer 2, who has paid in 2012 and 2014.

Comment: Where are the names in your example result?

Comment: Customers, it would be the customer Name.  So I would end up with a list of customer who have not paid this year, but paid in the last two years.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using the following solution and temporary tables;

```
DROP temporary table IF EXISTS LapsedRPT;'

Create temporary table  LapsedRPT
SELECT IDno, 
Concat(IDNo,' - ',Fname,' ',Lname) as Fullname
FROM Payments
GROUP BY FullName
having year(max(ddate)) < year(now());
```

---

```
Select 
year(now()) as CurrentYear,
Year(pdate) as PYr,
quarter(pdate) as PQTR,
concat(year(pdate),'-Q',quarter(ddate)) as YrQtr,
Fullname,
sum(amt) as Amt
from LapsedRPT
Where year(pdate) > Year(now())-3
Group by FullName, pyr, yrQtr;
```